# Android Volley or Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-volley

Android newbie here. Can someone help me understand the usecases for which I should be using GCM and for which I should use Volley?
I understand, GCM is push-pull type asynchronous messaging with a small message payload. If all my networking request fit within the GCM payload, would GCM be a better option for non-notification type of networking or should I consider using Volley?

Comment: They do not do the same so they cannot be compared. Volley could also be any other networking library. Volley = client seeks contact with server, GCM = server seeks contact with client

Comment: They are two completely different things and I believe you are looking for something else.

Comment: Thanks. For the sake of simplicity, I want to send some data to the server from a 'requester' app - have the server process it - send notification to all eligible apps that can act possibly reply back - send reply to the 'requester' app. Would it be wise to use GCM for all of these communications? or Should I be using Volley for the 'requester' app request-response cycle and GCM for notifying other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

GCM is great for notifying, and publishing data to lots of devices at the same time. Also things like chats, stuff that is based on time-critical handling.

Volley is rather for managing / queueing network request, if you happen to have lots and lots of request in your app, maybe even from several sources. They can be queued, canceled etc.

Comment: Thanks. For the sake of simplicity, I want to send some data to the server from a 'requester' app - have the server process it - send notification to all eligible apps that can act possibly reply back - send reply to the 'requester' app.  Would it be wise to use GCM for all of these communications? or Should I be using Volley for the 'requester' app request-response cycle and GCM for notifying other apps.

Comment: GCM is your way to go. Absolutely designed for your purposes. Take a look at the demo app, you will find most of the things you want to do in there: https://github.com/google/gcm

Answer (score 0):

**So , you need to know here Why Volley and GoogleCloudMessaging for ?**

**Volley :**

Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster. Volley is available through the open AOSP repository.

Volley offers the following benefits:

1 . Automatic scheduling of network requests.

2 . Multiple concurrent network connections.

3 . Transparent disk and memory response caching with standard HTTP cache coherence.

4 . Support for request prioritization.

5 . Cancellation request API. You can cancel a single request, or you can set blocks or scopes of requests to cancel.

6 . Ease of customization, for example, for retry and backoff.

7 . Strong ordering that makes it easy to correctly populate your UI with data fetched asynchronously from the network.

8 . Debugging and tracing tools

**GoogleCloudMessaging :**

According to Google documentation :
Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is a free service that enables developers to send messages between servers and client apps. This includes downstream messages from servers to client apps, and upstream messages from client apps to servers.

E.g .

A lightweight downstream message could inform a client app that there is new data to be fetched from the server, as in the case of a "new email" notification. For use cases such as instant messaging, a GCM message can transfer up to 4kb of payload to the client app. The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to and from the target client app.